# What is a backward compatible version of PHP 7's Anonymous Class

Tags: php

```
$gen = NEW CLASS {

    public function Num() {

        $number = mt_rand('0','9');

            function Duplicate($number) {
                $number = $number.$number;
                return $number;
            }

        return Duplicate($number);
    }

};
```

What would be a way to get the function above called like below in older versions of PHP:

```
 echo $gen->Num();
```

Comment: There isn't one. You have to create a 'normal' class, i.e. with a name. Older versions of PHP are very definite about classes. They always have a name.

Comment: @RyanVincent No way to call a class through a variable name?

Comment: @RyanVincent The stuff above is really for illustration. Obviously the actual application of a class would contain many functions.

Comment: You can call a class through a variable name. There is nothing against storing a class instance in a variable. i.e. `$gen = new RandomGenerator();` then do: `$gen->Num();`. It just needs a class name.

Comment: @RyanVincent You mean `NAMEOFCLASS::$gen->Num()`? If so I know of that.

Comment: No, i really mean storing a class instance  (object) in a variable. Not a static instance variable. PHP knows that variables can contain objects and parses them exactly as you expect.

Comment: @RyanVincent Need to have a class `RandomGenerator { }` defined first correct? Then convert it to an object `$gen = new RandomGenerator();`.

Comment: Exactly :) That is the way to do it. Even in PHP 7 I would be tempted to declare a separate class. It will be easier to locate and modify if it needs to be changed  rather than search code for it? The only 'extra' added by PHP 7 is to be able to declare a class 'inline', in the  same manner as functions (closures).

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks :) I love how `NEW CLASS { };` ends with a semicolon makes it way easier for me to know where my class ends, before I'd put comments. Um you've answered my question, please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: May I suggest that you post an answer yourself. My answer would add nothing new to the subject. I enjoyed assisting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions to your problem

- Create normal named class like @Ryan Vincent mentioned in comment,
- Create new class through [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)